# Moving Marker Missing

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

The marker doesn't show up. It doesn't throw any errors either. I'm trying to get the marker to move across the map as the JSON object is updating. What am I doing wrong? I can't find anyone else with the same problem as mine

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(map);
    List<MarkerOptions> markerOptions = new ArrayList<>();


    Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 50, conf);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);



    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
}




public void animateMarker(final Marker marker, final LatLng toPosition,
                          final boolean hideMarker) {


    MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);





    final Handler handler = new Handler() {

    };
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Projection proj = mMap.getProjection();
    Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
    final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);
    final long duration = 500;

    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {



            jobj = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("http://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544");


            try {
                Double longit = jobj.getDouble("longitude");
                Double lat =  jobj.getDouble("latitude");


             marker.setTitle("ISS");


                marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, longit));
                CameraUpdate center= CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(lat, longit));
                CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, longit),3);
                googleMap.animateCamera(center);
                googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }


            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                    / duration);












            if (t < 1.0) {
                // Post again 16ms later.
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
            } else {
                if (hideMarker) {
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger or added some logging?  That could help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: Try following the video demo by Google devs in this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKfZsCKSXVQ&feature=youtu.be). The full source code is in this [Github repo](https://gist.github.com/broady/6314689). Hope that helps.